# Changing table numbers using pkg:stargazer for R

Tags: r, formatting, stargazer

I'm trying to make several tables for a paper I'm writing using stargazer, but every table comes out saying "Table 1:" followed by my intended title. Is there a way to keep it from printing that, or at least change the table number?

Edit: Name of package is stargazer, as mentioned above. It's not an issue with a specific data frame or regression, but any stargazer table I try to create. This is the code that's giving me trouble--the title of the table is printed as "Table 1: Table 1: Share of battle deaths that occurred in intrastate conflicts (%)"

```
\begin{table}[htb] \centering  
  \caption{Table 1: Share of battle deaths that occurred in intrastate conflicts (\%)}  
  \label{}  
\footnotesize   

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} c c }  
\\[-1.8ex]\hline  
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  
Years & Intrastate.conflict.battle.deaths \\  
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  
1950s & $8$ \\  
1960s & $29$ \\  
1970s & $43$ \\  
1980s & $67$ \\  
1990s & $92$ \\  
2000-2002 & $93$ \\  
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  
\normalsize  
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
```

Edit edit: sorry, I'm new to this, and I realize now what you meant by the code.

```
stargazer(battle_deaths, title = "Table 1: Share of battle deaths that occurred in intrastate conflicts (\%)", summary = FALSE, notes = "Source: Lacina and Gleiditsch 2005")
```

Comment: This is a coding website. You should post name of package, data in format that can be cut and pasted (best done with dput) and code that is producing problems.

Comment: Actually the name of the package is "stargazer" (and since it is not a commonly mentioned package in Rhelp or S,O I thought it might be an external program.) The output is interesting but you didn't include thecode that produced it.

Comment: My guess after looking at the documentation and running some examples is that you have not told us how you are producing this output. I see no instances where stargazer itself adds those "Title" captions although they do appear in teh vignette, so I suspect that Sweave or knitr or ...?... are behind the scenes with some sort of markup procedure in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that `stargazer` has a `title` argument, right? (see page 2 of the docs: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf). Minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
model <- lm(price ~ color + clarity,data=diamonds)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(model, title="Your title here")
```

Don't number your tables by hand. LaTeX is perfectly capable of doing that for you.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware that stargazer has a title argument--I didn't put my code above at first, but I'm giving it a title of "Table 1: Share of battle deaths that occurred in intrastate conflicts (\%)", and it's printing "Table 1: Table 1: ..." In your example, the code would give me a table with a title of "Table 1: Your title here", which is fine, except I can't change that number. Every table I make is Table 1, which is the problem.

Comment: Ah, I see now. But then it would seem your problem isn't so much with stargazer than with LaTeX. Ordinarily LaTeX will number all tables in a document consecutively so if the table above is the second one in the document it _should_ get a title of "Table 2:...". If it isn't doing this properly, you should hunt for the bug in your LaTeX source, stargazer is working just as expected. If, for some reason, you want to override LaTeX's numbering, you can simply put `\setcounter{table}{value}` before the code that stargazer gives you and set `value` to any value you wish.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation and the help!